# Python - Looking up a line in a text file, converting to dictionary if a match is found and then working with the new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got an arbitrary text file that I've formatted such that I should be able to use eval() to turn it into a dictionary. It might read something like:

"{'User_id': u_1255248528}"

"{'User_id': u_1255248523}"

Now what I want to do is create a function that takes a User_id as an argument, and searches up the relevant line in the text file, and converts it into a dictionary. So function(u_1255248528) should create a dictionary {'User_id': u_1255248523}.

My solution so far is:

```
def function(user_id):
        with open('file.txt','r') as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                if user_id in line:
                    Dict=eval(line)
                    print(Dict)
        return(Dict[user_id])

login('u_1255248528')
```

Ideally `return(Dict[user_id])` would output u_1255248523. Once I have this I can hopefully generalise it to other fields. We might have "{'User_id': u_1255248528, 'blah':blah}" as a dictionary object and I want to be able to access Dict[blah].

But `return(Dict[user_id])` outputs "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'"

I've had a look around online and think I understand why this error occurs, I seem to be getting a string object (which can only be indexed by integer). I've seen some suggestions for literal_eval for similar problems but I can't use the ast module for this. Any help in making this into something workable would be appreciated.

Comment: `"{'User_id': u_1255248523}"` isn't valid Python, unless you have a variable named `u_1255248523`.

Comment: Instead of `eval`, consider using [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle) or [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json). No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You call, but never define, `login`.

Comment: My bad on "{'User_id': u_1255248523}", just trying to create a format that can be evaluated as a dictionary. Unfortunately I can't use pickle or JSON libraries either. At this point I'm thinking of going back to the start and thinking of a new solution. Maybe it's easier to turn the whole file into a dict and then look up the line I want? Not sure yet.

Comment: Not exactly sure about this method but seem to have found a solution where I can create a list using a line of a text file as an input. Then assigning the list indices to make key, value pairs.
Can post my solution if it matters but I think we might be able to mark this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to reshape your users file into formal json. You also likely what to create a tree with a key of the userid. Perhaps something like this:

**users.json**

```json
{
    "u_1255248528": {
        "user_id": "u_1255248528",
        "password": "...",
        "name": "dwwbndjwd"
    },

    "u_1255248528": {
        "user_id": "u_1255248523",
        "password": "...",
        "name": "jonSG"
    }
}
```

Now you can load that via the `json` package and pick out the user by id.

```py
import json
def login(user_id):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as file_in:
        users = json.load(file_in)
        return users.get(user_id)

print(login('u_1255248528'))
print(login('u_xxxxxxxxxx'))
```